# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a normal operator to be self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

What  are the necessary and sufficient conditions under which a normal operator becomes self-adjoint.

Comment: "Becomes self-adjoint"? How?? By magics, an operation...what do you *really* mean here?

Comment: If not only $T^* T=TT^*$ but also $T=T^*$ XD

Comment: For example, in the complex inner product space the necessary/sufficient condition is all the eigenvalues are real. I am asking in general. No magic...

Comment: The it is not "becomes", but rather: what are sufficient and necessary conditions for a normal operator to be self-adjoint...